# Entity Manager / persistance file structure

Tags: java, orm, jpa, persistence, ejb-3.0

The title isn't clear as I couldn't think of one but, I have an EJB project and am trying to play with JPA. To create the entity manager I am injecting it in via annotations

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="testConnection")  
private EntityManager em;
```

When I run a test query which I believe to be fine

```
Query userQuery = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM TestUser u WHERE u.username = 'test' u.password = 'test'");
tu = (TestUser) userQuery.getSingleResult();
```

I get an exception which points toward the EJB not being able to create the entity manager.

The strange thing is that when I run

```
tu = (TestUser) em.find(TestUser.class, id);
```

it works fine

My project structure is

```
  EAR
    EJB
    EJB Client
    JPA
       persistance.xml
```

and I guess this is the main problem

> SEVERE: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName testConnection

The individual projects are currently linked using dependencies.

So any thoughts?

Thanks
Jon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have an EJB project and am trying to play with JPA. To create the entity manager I am injecting it in via annotation

The annotation part itself looks correct.

> when I run a test query which i believe to be fine

I don't think it is, it is at least missing an AND in the WHERE clause. But I would write it like this actually:

```
Query userQuery = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM TestUser u WHERE u.username = :name AND u.password = :password");
userQuery.setParameter("name", "test");
userQuery.setParameter("password", "test");
tu = (TestUser) userQuery.getSingleResult();
```

> I get an exception which points toward the EJB not being able to create the entity manager. The strange thing is that when I run (...) it works fine.

That's strange indeed given the exception that you get.

> My project structure is (...)

I don't know if it's a typo or not but it's `persistence.xml`, not `persistance.xml`, and it should be located in a META-INF directory of the root of the persistence unit.

> So any thoughts?

Fix the query, fix the `persistence.xml` packaging. Also please provide its content and the full stack trace.

Comment: ahh thank you ever so much, 
the persistence name was a typo.

it was the blasted query (i cant belive i didnt see it myself)
i am surprised at the error it gave, as a result of a malformed query.

Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an entity manager once, but at the moment, I'm unable to access the code, but have a look at this page and the ones linked at the bottom:

http://www.javabeat.net/articles/91-ejb-30-entity-manager-2.html