# how inject entityManager to EJB from other EJBModule

Tags: java, jpa, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

I have 2 ejb-module in my project, ejb-module1 and ejb-module2. ejb-module1 contain entity clases and persistence unit, there is a ejb with a Entity Manager like this:

```
@Stateful
public class ErpTools implements ErpToolsLocal {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "erp-ejbPU")
private EntityManager em;


public EntityManager getEm() {
    return em;
}

public void setEm(EntityManager em) {
    this.em = em;
}
```

in ejb-module2 i have other ejb that need use entity manager from ejb-module1,
i try with this,

```
  String ejbql = "SELECT e from CtEmpresaCliente e ORDER BY e.idCliente ASC";        
  Query query = this.erpTools.getEm().createQuery(ejbql);
  empresaClientes = query.getResultList();
```

but send this exception:

```
"Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName erp-ejbPU"
debuging in this point Query query = this.erpTools.getEm().createQuery(ejbql);
this.erpTools.getEm() is not null.
```

note: Using `Netbeans`, `JPA`, `JEE6`, `EJB 3.1`

Comment: Do you have a persistence.xml with "erp-ejbPU" as persistence unit name?

Comment: yes: <persistence-unit name="erp-ejbPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>dsct</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>

Comment: It is strange because it looks like is not taking the persistence.xml. Do you have the persistence.xml inside of META-INF folder?

Comment: the problem is not with persistence unit, maybe the Im not using Container-Managed Entity Managers or Application-Managed Entity Managers correctly... because have difference in inject functionality

Comment: This thread could be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386362/entity-manager-persistance-file-structure . So, even the exception is "Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName erp-ejbPU" the cause can be another thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calls to EJBs that are in different modules are similar to remote invocations in the sense that they use pass by value semantics and undergo serialization / de-serialization. In this case the network is not used, but all other aspects of the remote invocations are still happening.

What this means for you is that even though you get a non null `EntityManager` from another EJB module, it is serialized / de-serialized and by the time it makes it to the other EJB module it no longer refers to a valid persistence context (since it does not exist in the calling EJB module).

Comment: @PersistenceUnit
    EntityManagerFactory emf;
    

    public EntityManager getEm() {
        return (EntityManager) emf.createEntityManager();
    }

Comment: http://piotrnowicki.com/2012/11/communication-between-ejb-modules-in-the-same-application-server/ Here they explain what I mean. I can't really post an example because the described behaviour is in app server code. However, I am quite surprised that what you did worked.